# How to rename while copy without change the extension?

Tags: php

I need to rename the filename of pdf files while copying them without change the extension.

```
$title = strip_tags($link1->plaintext);
$pdfLink = strip_tags($link2->title);
copy($pdfLink, $title);
```

I wanna change the filename with `$title` but the extension also changed become type:file. How to keep the extension file ? thank you

Comment: Keep the extension? If you want to *keep* it, you need to add it.

Comment: @hakra to keep the ori file extension so they will not change. Add what ?

Comment: So you have no clue how to *get* the file-extension of a filename? > http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: @hakra  I don't know about it before, thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `pathinfo` to get the file extention

```
if(file_exists($pdfLink))
{
    $titleExtention = pathinfo($pdfLink,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    copy($pdfLink, $title . ".". $titleExtention) ;
}
```