# How to get File-Type of an Image in a HTML page?

Tags: php

I've wrote a short script to upload images from a URL so as not to hotlink to them. If the image extension is not a .jpeg then the image that is uploaded is broken. I can't figure out how to preserve the file extension or filename so I've had to add a timestamp to them and a static extension.

```
<?php

    ini_set('user_agent', 'TEST/1.0 +http://127.0.0.1');

    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.discogs.com/viewimages?release='.$_POST["album_id"]);

    // Grab the coverart
    $img = $html->find('.image_frame', 0);

    $url = $img->src;

    $file = file_get_contents($url);

    $image = 'discogs_'.time().'_image.jpeg';

    file_put_contents('/path/to/file/'.$image,$file);

    echo $image;

?>
```

**Updated code with Baba's help**: http://codepad.org/3zH3B882

Comment: You should be detecting content type from the `Content-Type` response header, **not** from file name extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename while copy without change the extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556617/how-to-rename-while-copy-without-change-the-extension)

Comment: You should consider to use the REST API of the site to obtain the release pictures: http://www.discogs.com/developers/ - it also handles rate-limiting which is per day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image extension using file_get_contents php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794325/how-to-get-image-extension-using-file-get-contents-php)

Comment: @hakra - Thanks for the info, but unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to use the API.

Comment: A REST API is actually pretty similar like `file_get_contents` (actually the same), however, you do not need the really crappy simple HTML DOM Parser, but only `json_decode` and then you have the data. Really simple. And worth to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `getimagesize` with `image_type_to_extension`

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.discogs.com/viewimages?artist=Test+%282%29";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$img = $html->find('.image_frame', 0);
$info = getimagesize($img->src);
$extention = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);
$image = 'discogs_'.time().'_image' . $extention;
echo $image ;
```

Output

```
discogs_1348438953_image.gif
```